# multicol is creating weird behavior by leaving almost-blank pages

Tags: multicol, mdframed, columns, multicolumn

I am using the `multicol` package to create a three-column formula sheet. I am also using the `mdframed` package to write theorems, definitions, etc. in differently colored boxes. Here is the result:

[image]

As you see, for some reason `multicol` just stops adding content to a page and skips directly to the next page to continue filling... Do you know of a fix to this? Thank you!

Here is the main file (the individual chapters are in their own files):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,mathtools,bm,mathabx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1mm,paperwidth=20.9cm,paperheight=29.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzsymbols}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{enumitem}
%\usepackage{newclude}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    % Something here
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue
}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\input{page_style.tex}
\input{boxes.tex}
\input{newcommands.tex}
\input{tikz_styles.tex}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols*}{3}
\tiny

\input{Proofs_and_Functions}
\input{Introduction_to_Algebra}
\input{Introduction_to_Analysis}
\input{Time_varying_linear_systems_Solutions}
\input{LTI_systems_solutions_and_tfs}
\input{Stability}
\input{Inner_product_spaces}
\input{Controllability_and_Observability}
\input{State_Feedback_and_Observer_Design}

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please can you make your code minimal?

Comment: If you think it's necessary, I thought to keep it this way in case someone sees that there is a conflicting package that I'm using.

Comment: but the most inportant is the input text that produce the problem and you don't post it :-)

Comment: Well, it's 1000+ lines long and the problem sometimes appears, sometimes disappears while I modify the contents. Surely it's a bug in multicol. The input text is nothing but text, sometimes encapsulated in mdframed boxes.

Comment: `Surely it's a bug in multicol` ! are you sure? please help us help you try to find the minimal code that give problem?

Comment: I'll see a bit later if I can reproduce it :)

Comment: I think it may actually be an [mdframed bug](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/291539/mdframed-breaking-pages-in-weird-places).